# Export xlsx file using php

Tags: php, http-headers, phpexcel, xlsx

I need to download a file in XLS & XLSX format, I tried Many Way but it is not working.

My download code is as follows:

```
$file = "Reports.xlsx";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Both i Tried :

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');  -  not working
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); -  not working
```

For Xls:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8;");  - Working for Xls
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not working". Do you get any error messages? Does it download the wrong file? Does it send the wrong headers? Does it eat your pet hamster?

Comment: i tried to download xlsx format using content-type( application/octet-stream. etc), The Error Msg - Excel file cannot be open 'report.xlsx', because the file format or file extension is not a valid.

Comment: Well you should be using `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for an `.xlsx` file, not `application/octet-stream`

Comment: I'm assuming that you're getting the error message when you try to open the file in MS Excel.... make sure that your script doesn't generate any other output either before or after the `readfile($file);` line

Comment: Open the downloaded file in a text editor, and check for any leading/trailing whitespace characters, check for PHP error messages inside the file (e.g. headers already sent), or anything like html markup

Comment: And are you actually using the `PHPExcel` library as you've tagged this question `PHPExcel`?

Comment: I tried using `PHPExcel` library, in this also i can not able to download xlsx format